# how to make a simple if statement is too long?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

This is my first bash script, to get the data I want time for each hour of data reduction, I created a bash script that is already running, but I think it is too long to use the statement "if ... else", possibly with loops for, while and until?

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(date +"%H")
y=$(sed -n "/END_TIME/=" file.txt)
if [ $x = 00 ]; then
        s=$(($y-24))
        echo "this time 00:00"
elif [ $x = 23 ]; then
        s=$(($y-1))
        echo "this time 23:00"
elif [ $x = 22 ]; then
        s=$(($y-2))
        echo "this time 22:00"
elif [ $x = 21 ]; then
        s=$(($y-3))
        echo "this time 21:00"
elif [ $x = 20 ]; then
        s=$(($y-4))
        echo "this time 20:00"
        .
        .
        .
elif [ $x = 01 ]; then
        s=$(($y-23))
        echo "this time 01:00"
else
        echo "this time not data"
fi

z=$(awk 'NR=='$s' {print $0}' file.txt)

#print
echo "Time : " $x
echo "Line End_time : " $y
echo "Show Line Data : " $z
```

This sample data file.txt :

```
0 3419973
1 2302205
2 1535190
3 1045063
4 895020
5 1275980
.
.
.
.
21 6953924
22 6423911
23 5075690
END_TIME
```

If I want to get the data in "file.txt" when at 21:00, then it will print:

```
Time           : 21:00
Line END_time  : 24 
Show Line Data : 21 6953924 *(I was looking for this)*
```

this run with cron. if can help me?

Comment: Use a switch statement instead of if statements.

Comment: I want him to run automatically without the case statement. Thank you for your suggestion @AndersonGreen , does anyone other than a switch statement ?

Comment: `date '+%H'` will never return 24 for midnight. From the man page: "`%H     hour (00..23)`"

Comment: And it seems that all you want to do is calculating previous hour value from current hour. So actually `s=$(( $x - 1))` should be enough, or not? For `$x` being zero you'd use an `if` expression to set `s` to 23. All these `if`s seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: If this is really what you want to do: `date --date="1hour ago" '+%H'` is most convenient for GNU date (on most Linux versions) .

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I was less clear in asking, I mean like I updated the question .. Thank you for your suggestion @try-catch-finally

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `case` statement? Why do you think the `if` is "too long"?

Comment: This my script will running with crontab , I think if the if statement will be recurrent and long long in his process, if there is a way you use the case statement to the script above? @Keith Thompson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can reduce the cases to:

```
case $x in
    24)
        s = $(($y-1))
        echo "this time 00:00"
        ;;
    23 | 22 | ... | 01)             # or [01][0-9] | 2[0-3])
        s = $(($y - 25 + $x))
        echo "this time $x:00"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "this time not data"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks you suggestion @hjpotter92 , if I like the question I've just updated, whether can also use this?

Comment: Why don't you use ``((s=y-1))`` and ``((s=y-25+x))`` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(date +"%H")
y=24

unset time
for h in `seq 0 23`
do
    if [ $x -eq $h ]
    then
        time="${x}:00"
        s=$(( $y - ( 24 - $x ) ))
        break
    fi
done

if [ -z "$time" ]
then
    echo "this time not data"
else
    echo "this time $time"

    #proceed with awk
fi
```

Comment: `-z` is true if string is empty, false otherwise

Comment: thanks @Sergey Fedorov , still there which makes me confused is this " if [ -z "$time" ]" , what is meant by "-z" ?